# JS Problems by displaying fetched MySQL data in 2 different div boxes [PHP, MySQL & JS]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm learning JS (without JQuery for now!) and got a problem with my code and need your help!

I'm working on a code which fetch the **image title** out of a database and put it in a kinda list.
If the user clicks on the title, a other div box pops up and shows the **image describtion**.

**My Problem is that my code only display the first "img_descr" in each popup box.**
And because the "img_title" list is dynamically (it depends on what the user types in the search bar) it makes it even more a bit difficult.

Below I will paste a simple version of my code with php code and below that i will past a snippet. (by clicking on the "play" button you can see a **simulation** of my code). 
Click on each title and you will see, only 1 describtion will show up for each title.

▽ **Here you can see a simple version of my code with PHP code** ▽

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XY</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="frame">
        <?php
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
            echo "<div class='click_box'>";
              echo "<a class='img_id'>ID: ".$row['img_id']."</a><br>";
              echo "<div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>".$row['img_title']."</b></a></div>";
            echo "</div>";

          echo "<div id='popup'>";
              echo "<div class='img_descr'><a>Descr: <b>".$row['img_descr']."</b></a></div>";
          echo "</div>";
          }
        ?>
    </div>

    <style>
      *{
        font-family: arial;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }
      body{
        background-color:rgba(100,100,100);
      }
      .click_box{
        height: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color:rgba(150,150,150);
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
      .img_id{
        color:rgba(100,100,100);
      }
      .img_title{
        color: white;
      }
      .img_title:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color:rgba(50,50,50);
      }
      #popup{
        position: absolute;
        height: 230px;
        width: 350px;
        top: 10px;
        left: 170px;
        background-color:rgba(50,50,50);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      .img_descr{
        color: white;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
    let myarray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.img_title'))
    let bg = document.getElementById('popup');
    myarray.map((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", e=>{
      // retrieve the actual value of opacity for bg
      bgStyle = window.getComputedStyle(bg, null).getPropertyValue("opacity");
      // if the opacity is "0" make it "1" otherwhise make it "0"
      let opacity = bgStyle == "0" ? "1" : 0;
      // use the opacity variable
      bg.setAttribute("style", `opacity:${opacity};`);
    })
    })
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

▽ **Here you can see a snippet i created, but without PHP code** ▽
there you can see, only the first "**img_descr"** do work!

```js
let myarray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.img_title'))
        let bg = document.getElementById('popup');
        myarray.map((e) => {
        e.addEventListener("click", e=>{
          // retrieve the actual value of opacity for bg
          bgStyle = window.getComputedStyle(bg, null).getPropertyValue("opacity");
          // if the opacity is "0" make it "1" otherwhise make it "0"
          let opacity = bgStyle == "0" ? "1" : 0;
          // use the opacity variable
          bg.setAttribute("style", `opacity:${opacity};`);
        })
        })
```

```css
*{
            font-family: arial;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
          }
          body{
            background-color:rgba(100,100,100);
          }
          .click_box{
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color:rgba(150,150,150);
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
          }
          .img_id{
            color:rgba(100,100,100);
          }
          .img_title{
            color: white;
          }
          .img_title:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
            color:rgba(50,50,50);
          }
          #popup{
            position: absolute;
            height: 230px;
            width: 350px;
            top: 10px;
            left: 170px;
            background-color:rgba(50,50,50);
            opacity: 0;
          }
          .img_descr{
            color: white;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>XY</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="frame">
        
            <div class='click_box'>
              <a class='img_id'>ID: 1</a><br>
              <div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>Golden Retriever</b></a></div>
            </div>

            <div id='popup'>
                <div class='img_descr'><a>Descr:  <b>UK:DFYDFBAERSDFBYDFBYDFydfbydfBaeydfb1311y</b></a></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class='click_box'>
              <a class='img_id'>ID: 2</a><br>
              <div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>Appenzeller Sennenhund</b></a></div>
            </div>

            <div id='popup'>
                <div class='img_descr'><a>Descr:  <b>Swiss:erydfydfbrehaydydfbydfydbaerydf2ydfb</b></a></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class='click_box'>
              <a class='img_id'>ID: 3</a><br>
              <div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>German Shepard</b></a></div>
            </div>

            <div id='popup'>
                <div class='img_descr'><a>Descr:  <b>Germany:ydf3d1fby3df1by3dfb6ydfb31ydf31ydf</b></a></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class='click_box'>
              <a class='img_id'>ID: 4</a><br>
              <div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>Alaskan Klee Kai</b></a></div>
            </div>

            <div id='popup'>
                <div class='img_descr'><a>Descr:  <b>USA:f3ngxfgxfgnxfxfgnxfg3xf31gnxfgner6ae13</b></a></div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
      </body>
      
     </html>
```

It seems it have to do something with the "id="popup"... and if i change the popup div from "id" to "class", change "document.getElementById" to "document.getElementsByClassName" and change the css "#popup" to ".popup", nothing work then. 

**If you would make it totally different, please let me know. (i'm a js beginner)**

Comment: First of all - you shouldn't have more than one element with the same id on your page. ID should be unique. Can I use a jQuery to solve your problem?

Comment: below the snippet, i said i tried to replace the id with class, but then nothing worked. yes you can try it with jquery, but i really want to learn java script first, before i use any library, maybe someone else could translate your jquery code into pure js code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you have to replace the multiple popup ids with classes (in css and html)

Here is the js code with the corrections.

```
let myarray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.click_box'));
myarray.map((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let popups = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.popup'));
    popups.map((popup) => {
        popup.setAttribute("style", 'opacity:0');
    })
    let bg = e.nextElementSibling;
    bg.setAttribute("style", 'opacity:1');
  })
})
```

here is the process :

- get the click boxes (notice that I use `.click_box` as my click target)
- get all popups and hide them using `opacity: 0`
- get the element after the clicked one using [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling). as the click event is on clickBox, the next element will be the popup
- show the popup using `opacity: 1`

jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/1L0ehpuy/18/

---

**warning** : this code depends on the html markup to work properly : you have to keep the `popup` right after the `click_box` element otherwise the `nextElementSibling` won't be the popup

---

here is the php code with classes instead of ids. with this php code and the js above, everything should be fine

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='click_box'>";
    echo "<a class='img_id'>ID: ".$row['img_id']."</a><br>";
    echo "<div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>".$row['img_title']."</b></a></div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='popup'>";
    echo "<div class='img_descr'><a>Descr: <b>".$row['img_descr']."</b></a></div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

---

new version to hide the popup on 2nd click

```
let myarray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.click_box'));
myarray.map((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let bg = e.nextElementSibling;
    if (bg.style.opacity == 1) {
      bg.setAttribute("style", 'opacity:0');
    } else {
      let popups = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.popup'));
      popups.map((popup) => {
        popup.setAttribute("style", 'opacity:0');
      })
      bg.setAttribute("style", 'opacity:1');
    }
  })
})
```

there are not many changes : at the begining of the function, I just added a `if` to check if the related popup is already shown. if so, I hide it.

fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/1L0ehpuy/21/

Comment: in the jsfiddle it seems to work and I thank you for that, but when i try to implement this in my php code with fetched data, then it doesn't work... Like i said at the bottom of this question (i tried to change id with class, and nothing worked then). It seems only the ".popup" makes some problem, i have no idea why, it makes no seens, that it doesn't work with class instead of id ... i have the js script at the end of the body tag, but i also tried out to put it in the header, it also doesn't work for some reason....

Comment: you must use class for popup otherwise you will have many html elements with the same id so it will work only for the first element. Are there any errors in the browser console when you use the code with classes ?

Comment: @user10235329 if there are no errors and the result is still not correct, can you edit your question with the new code you use and also add the generated code

Comment: before i had the same php code changes like you in your update (just use class instead of id), and then I copied your version in my code and now it works! I have no idea why! :D Thank you very much! :)

Comment: A other question, what do i have to change that: 1) the user clicks on the title -> the popup show up. 2) if the user clicks on the title again --> the popup will disappear 3) and fianly if there is already a popup shown up and the user clicks on a other title, only the describtion will change. I hope it is not too hard for you to solve. Here in my question is a other user ("David") who made it with jquery and he also inserted a snippet below the answer, you can check the snippet simulation by clicking on the play button to see what i try to reach :)

Answer (score 1):

This is new, edited version of my code. I've transfered every jQuery code into pure JavaScript. I've also tried to comment my JS code so it will be easier for you to understand it.

```js
//Pass the clicked element in function 'openPopup' and name it as 'el'
//We are passing the clicked element from the HTML, you can see it at "onclick='openPopup(this)'"
//The word 'this' is a variable for current element

function openPopup(el){
  var parent = el.parentElement;
  var child = null;
  //Loop through children of parent element
  for (var i = 0; i <= parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
    //Only if children has class, check if children's class contains 'popup'
    if(parent.childNodes[i].classList){
     if (parent.childNodes[i].classList.contains("popup")) {
      //If we have the popup element, add it to a variable 'child'
        child = parent.childNodes[i];
        break;
      } 
    }      
  }
  
  //If assigned popup is opened
  if(child.classList.contains("visible")){
  
    //Remove class 'visible' from the popup element (popup is stored in 'child' variable)
    child.classList.remove("visible");

  } else {

    //Close all popups by removing class 'visible' from all popups
    var popups = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");
    for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
        popups[i].classList.remove("visible");       
    }
    
    //Add class 'visible' to popup assigned to our button (still stored in 'child' variable)
    child.classList.add("visible");
  }
}
```

```css
*{
            font-family: arial;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
          }
          body{
            background-color:rgba(100,100,100);
          }
          .click_box{
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color:rgba(150,150,150);
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
          }
          .img_id{
            color:rgba(100,100,100);
          }
          .img_title{
            color: white;
          }
          .img_title:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
            color:rgba(50,50,50);
          }
          .popup{
            position: absolute;
            height: 230px;
            width: 350px;
            top: 10px;
            left: 170px;
            background-color:rgba(50,50,50);
            display: none;
          }
          .popup.visible{
            display: block;
          }
          .img_descr{
            color: white;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>XY</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="frame">
            
            <div class="frame__wrapper">
              <div class='click_box' onclick='openPopup(this)'>
                <a class='img_id'>ID: 1</a><br>
                <div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>Title 1</b></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class='popup'>
                <div class='img_descr'><a>Descr:  <b>Desc 1</b></a></div>
             </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="frame__wrapper">
              <div class='click_box' onclick='openPopup(this)'>
                <a class='img_id'>ID: 2</a><br>
                <div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>Title 2</b></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class='popup'>
                <div class='img_descr'><a>Descr:  <b>Desc 2</b></a></div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="frame__wrapper">
              <div class='click_box' onclick='openPopup(this)'>
                <a class='img_id'>ID: 3</a><br>
                <div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>Title 3</b></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class='popup'>
                <div class='img_descr'><a>Descr:  <b>Desc 3</b></a></div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="frame__wrapper">
              <div class='click_box' onclick='openPopup(this)'>
                <a class='img_id'>ID: 4</a><br>
                <div class='img_title'><a>Title: <b>Title 4</b></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class='popup'>
                <div class='img_descr'><a>Descr:  <b>Desc 4</b></a></div>
              </div>
           </div>

        </div>
      </body>
      
     </html>
```

Comment: This works like i need it, but i also need it as java script code ... Do you know someone, who could translate your jQuery code? When i'm asking a person, if he can also write his jquery code into js code, then the reaction is often: "ehm, ehm, ehm I got to go!" ^^

Comment: I will try to transform it into pure javascript.